# Deedle - Recursive mapping on a Series with an initial value

Tags: recursion, f#, deedle

I am attempting to create a new time series (Series[DateTime,float]) from an existing one of the same type, where the map to the new Series is **recursive** - for example:

```
NewSeries_T = NewSeries_T-1 + constant * OldSeries_T;
```

I have "NewSeries_0 = 1", as an initialization value for the new series.

I'm attempting to write a Series.map function that will do the job - I've got as far as the following non-working code, but I can't figure out the recursive part:

```
let rec newSeries = existingSeries |> Series.map (fun k v ->     
match k.Equals(initDate) with
| true -> 1
| false -> newSeries.LastValue() + constant * v
)
```

So, I think the trick is, how do I allow the function access to the "previous" value in the series to build this up recursively?

### Edit - Moved to answer below.

Comment: Look at `Series.scanValues`.

Comment: Thanks very much! That's got me to where I needed to go.

Comment: @calvinXS, why you don't want to write an answer?

Answer (score 3):

Based on Fyodor's reccomendation - the Series.scanValues does exactly what I need:

```
let initalEntry = Series([initDate], [init])

let newSeries= 
    existingSeries 
    |> Series.filter (fun k v -> k.Equals(initDate) = false) 
    |> Series.scanValues (fun n x-> lambda * n + (1.0 - lambda) * x ) init

newSeries.Merge(initalEntry)
```

I took away the first value, as I want this to return the "init" value at the start of the series, and merged this back at the end.